# regular expression MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

How can I write a regular expression to catch all the words (in MS-Word via script) that are not follow by specific characters, for example:
I would like to catch all the "write" words that does not follow by ':' char

`I write: write`

In this case the result will be:

`write`

Comment: Does it have to be VBA?  In the UI, you can hit Ctrl+H to get the advanced (i.e. legacy) **Find and Replace** dialog.  Check the **Use wildcards** option, and then for **Find what**, enter `write[!:]`.  This tells Word to find all instances of `write` that are not followed by any of the single characters after the `!` in the `[ ]` square brackets, which in your case would be the `:` colon.

Comment: You right, for some reason I can not mark you remark to "accepted answer" (can not see the button)

Comment: Comments cannot be marked as "accepted", so I'll convert to a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

(Converting to answer on asker's suggestion)

**If it doesn't have to be VBA:**

In the UI, you can hit Ctrl+H to get the advanced (i.e. legacy) **Find and Replace** dialog. Check the **Use wildcards** option, and then for **Find what**, enter `write[!:]`. This tells Word to find all instances of `write` that are not followed by any of the single characters after the `!` in the `[ ]` square brackets, which in your case would be the `:` colon.